How to allow external domains to scripts in CSP by nuxt-security module?
My config:
 security: {
    headers: {
      crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: getIsDev() ? 'unsafe-none' : 'require-corp',
      crossOriginOpenerPolicy: 'same-origin-allow-popups',
      crossOriginResourcePolicy: 'cross-origin',
      contentSecurityPolicy: GetCSPRules,
    },
    corsHandler: {
      origin: '*',
    },
  },

My rules returned in GetCSPRules:
'script-src': [
    "'self'",
    'https:',
    "'unsafe-inline'",
    'unsafe-eval',
    "'strict-dynamic'",
    `${CSP_RULES_SCRIPT_STRING}`,
],
'worker-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'blob:'],
'upgrade-insecure-requests': !isDev,

CSP_RULES_SCRIPT_STRING - is a array of domains strings joined to one string.
But after all I have blocked all external JS.
If I do it without nuxt-security module and adding stringg to head meta - works well.
What's wrong?
